LaTeX problems on the mathematics stack exchange website
When I am writing LaTeX to ask a question on the mathematics stack exchange, I cannot see the preview below where I am typing to see if my LaTeX is correct or not.
Furthermore, I cannot type a space by using a backslash and a colon, as it just renders a semicolon. instead I am having to use \text{ }
I am fairly new to using LaTeX, so these are probably fairly basic questions that are easily resolved, so please forgive my lack of knowledge, but I have never had these problems using LaTeX elsewhere.

Is there a “show preview” button and can you include the semicolon problem in an example?

I cannot find a "show preview" button. It was automatically updating for a few seconds at the beginning, but then stopped. It updated with the message 'draft saved', however only one time. Manually saving the draft again seems to do nothing for the preview.

As for the example of the semicolon thing, it appeared at the start of my question when setting up integration by parts with the following line: $Let;u;=;x$. Each instance of ; is meant to be a space. It seems to work in the comments though. I have put a backslash and then semicolon between each word in 'let u = x' in this comment and they are acting as spaces

I don't know the exact details, but drafts get saved only periodically. But, can you please include a snippet of LaTeX-code (or more accurately MathJax -code) that you think does not work as you wish. Edit the main post so that we can see the source code also (if you post it in a comment we don't see the source).

I get the vibe that you may have not realized that MathJax is only used to produce the formulas. In other words, LaTeX works only inside dollar signs. Also, looking at the source of the earlier revisions of your question (on Main), you had neglected to type \cos and used cos instead. That already leads to issues with the spacing (the same way it would inside a LaTeX-formula).

Ah okay, thank you for the advice. I'll retype my question with the dollar signs and the backslash for functions.

I found the issue. MathJax is still run on HTTP servers whereas the stack exchange is HTTPS, and on certain browsers, this causes some kind of compatibility issue. To word it simply, the issue was that my LaTeX was not rendering fully
I managed to fix the issue by using DuckDuckGo to run the Maths Stack Exchange website instead of chrome.

I have little knowledge with anything computing/website related, so my explanation won't be perfect, however i am answering my own post so that others with the same issue can see how to fix it.
